# How do I get rid of extra linebreaks <br> in rich text fields when using the Rich Text Editor on Sitecore 8.0?

Tags: richtext-editor

It doesn't happen on Internet Explorer (IE), but does on Firefox, Opera, and Chrome.

Comment: Can you clarify, is it the *Multi-Line Text Field* or the *Rich Text Field*. The title states both so it's confusing. Does this only happen in Content Editor, Experience Editor or both?

Comment: It's a rich text field.  Sorry for the confusion.  It happens in Content Editor and Experience Editor.

Comment: So you're seeing something like this http://www.telerik.com/forums/new-lines-content-in-ie-and-chrome and this? http://www.telerik.com/forums/inconsistent-behaviour-in-ie-and-chrome

Comment: Mark, what I'm seeing is similar, though not exactly the same.  If I open a rich-text field with Show Editor, don't change anything, then click Accept, a single <br> tag is added to the end of my text (visible when viewed in HTML).

Comment: Ok. Likely your issue is related though, even if I can't pinpoint exactly why and how.

Comment: I've seen a similar issue for Multi-Line Text field EE, turned out to be a Sitecore big in certain browsers, so not exactly the same... I would suggest you also raise a Sitecore Support ticket.

Answer (score 1):

From Sitecore Support:

> We registered the described behavior as a bug in the current version of the Sitecore CMS.
>   To track the future status of this bug report, please use the reference number 175677.
>   More information about public reference numbers can be found here:
>   https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/853187
>
> After deeper investigation I found that it is related to removing script tags and inline scripts from RTE field values before saving that is controlled by the following setting in the web.config file:
>   **setting name="HtmlEditor.RemoveScripts" value="true"**
>   You can set its value to “false” to resolve the issue.
>
> Alternatively, please use the link below to download the patch:
>   https://sitecore.app.box.com/s/7ra1r6s71ehqlbrg0h8s1i3bdbc28dgi
>   To install the patch follow the instructions from the readme file inside the package.

Using the web.config approach solved the issue.